# Can you win ship achievements using the TYPE B layouts?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

There are three achievements for each ship; you start with the **TYPE A** layout, and when you have completed two of the three achievements, you unlock the type **TYPE B** layout for that ship.

If you are trying to get the third ship achievement (just for the sake of completeness), can you use the **TYPE B** layout to do so, or can achievements only be won with the "default" **TYPE A** layout?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ship achievements *can* be won using the **TYPE B** layout.

In addition, if you already completed a ship achievement on **Easy** mode, [you can complete either of the two old achievements again](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85515/can-you-get-the-same-achievement-twice-on-easy-and-normal-difficulty) on **Normal**.

*Source: Testing in a personal play-through.*

*Here you can see the **Red-Tail** (the secondary layout of **The Kestrel Cruiser**) with only one HP remaining on the hull...*

[image: FTL - Red-Tail before repair]

*...and then earning [the **Tough Little Ship** achievement](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Ship_Achievements/Tough_Little_Ship) when it is repaired.*

[image: FTL - Red-Tail after repair, with "Tough Little Ship" achievement]